# Stmt not working

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I all ready read all the other topic but don't find solution. here my code

```
    $DevolverUser     =  $_SESSION['DevolverUser'];
    $DevolverPaswword =  $_SESSION['DevolverPaswword'];

    $query = " select puededevolver   ".
        "   from b_usuarios  ".
        "   where codpais = ? ".
        "   and usuario   = 'usuario' ".
        "   and PASSWORD = PASSWORD('password')";

    $stmt = $con ->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $pais );         
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($dato);

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo  $dato;
    }
```

if i change to

```
    $DevolverUser     =  $_SESSION['DevolverUser'];
    $DevolverPaswword =  $_SESSION['DevolverPaswword'];

    $query = " select puededevolver   ".
        "   from b_usuarios  ".
        "   where codpais = ? ".
        "   and usuario   = ? ".
        "   and PASSWORD = PASSWORD(?)";

    $stmt = $con ->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $pais, $DevolverUser, $DevolverPaswword  );            
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($dato);

    while($stmt->fetch()){
           echo $dato;
    }
```

it not work, if i trait just bind the user or only the passwork no work, Ony work with the $pais. I all ready check that all my variable are string. I don't know what else to check, please help.

Comment: How are you getting your password from db? If you just tske value from table and place here it wont work. Here it is password() version of passowrd, PASSWORD = PASSWORD(?) . You either take original text value or replace here with PASSWORD = ?

Comment: Where do you have `$pais` set?

Comment: BTW: The [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function is MySQL does ***not*** do what you think it does.  From the documentation: "PASSWORD() is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should *not* use it in your own applications."  I *highly* suggest using PHP's `password_hash`/`password_verify` instead.  See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: $pais is set in the setup() funtion, and   $DevolverUser ,
    $DevolverPaswword i get it from the user. but my cuestion is if i bind_param just the $pais and the  $DevolverUser it stop to work. So where is the error in that point.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** my bad, i assumed you are using `PDO` - instead you seem to use `mysqli`.

it's not `$stmt->bind_param()`, it's `$stmt->bindParam()`; and something like `$stmt->bind_result()` doesn't exist at all as far as i know. I am also wondering what you want to achieve with `PASSWORD(...)` in your SQL. i fixed everything i could so far:

```
$DevolverUser     =  $_SESSION['DevolverUser'];
$DevolverPaswword =  $_SESSION['DevolverPaswword'];

$query = " select puededevolver   ".
    "   from b_usuarios  ".
    "   where codpais = :codpais ".
    "   and usuario   = :usuario ".
    "   and PASSWORD = :password ";

$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":codpais", $pais);        
$stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $DevolverUser);        
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $DevolverPaswword);        
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
       echo $row["puededevolver"];
}
```

Comment: In MySQLi, it *is* [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).  [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is for PDO.

Comment: @Mihai ok, my bad. why do `mysqli` and `PDO` have to be so similar? no need to downvote tho.

Comment: Well, may be op using `mysqli` oop interface, so it could be `bind_param`

Comment: @Mihai i was talking about downvoting it in general. i know clarified that this answer assumes OP is using `PDO`.

Comment: As @Mihai, i left some comments.

Comment: Can i be more St&^%%   $DevolverUser  and $DevolverPaswword are no save in section jet the part when i was see it was the $post variable.  then i was deleted it by doing the $DevolverUser     =  $_SESSION['DevolverUser'];
$DevolverPaswword =  $_SESSION['DevolverPaswword'];  now work perfect.